# Easy way to convert logic to JSON file

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a mysql table that houses a node with it's respective parent located on a levelnumber.

I'm trying to convert this into a JSON file, right now when I'm calling the recursive functions to print out in order of parent -> child and print out a "-" for the levelnumber

For example:

If A is a parent of B and C and D are parents of B this is how they look in the table:

```
Node: A 
Parent: NULL 
levelnumber: 0

Node: B 
Parent: A 
levelnumber: 1

Node: C
Parent: B 
levelnumber: 2

Node: D 
Parent: B 
levelnumber: 2
```

Now I need to be able to print a JSON file so that this correlation would print out based on what's in this table.

I've tried doing it the hard way of actually printing out the lines but keep running into syntax errors, out of frustration I'm curious if anyone out here knows of a simpler way because it seems like a very simple port that would need to only occur once

Comment: What about getting the data into an array and then using json_encode?

Comment: But then getting this data into an array would be complicated, I'd have to parse it and print it out in some way keeping the parent children correlations intact.